# Trying to display output from the user input onto the same html screen

Tags: python, html, django, display

I'm sure this is not difficult, I'm just new to Django and would really appreciate some help.

I've been trying to take two inputs ('sentence' variable, and 'word' variable) as CharFields. Then take those two inputs and create a new output with them. I can get this to print on the console but not to display it on the html page.

Thank you.
Here is what I got.

--> form.html

```
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="content" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form }}
                    {% if output %}
                        <h3>{{ output }}</h3>
                    {% endif %}
                    <input type="submit" name="submit_cmd" value=Run />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

--> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import ContactForm
import subprocess as sp

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
nltk.download('wordnet')

def contact(request):
    syn = set()
    output = ""
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            sentence = form.cleaned_data['sentence']
            word = form.cleaned_data['word']

            for synonym in wordnet.synsets(word):
                for l in synonym.lemmas():
                    if l.name() != word:
                        syn.add(l.name().lower())

            for new_wrd in list(syn):
                print(sentence.replace(word, new_wrd))
                output += sentence.replace(word, new_wrd)


    return render(request, 'pk_app/form.html', {'form': form})
```

--> forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    sentence = forms.CharField(required=True)
    word = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `output` variable, but never attach it to the context dict that you return to the template.

```py
return render(request, 'pk_app/form.html', {'form': form, 'output': output})
```

Also: Are you sure it belongs *in* the HTML form element?

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was so close! Now I just need to style this whole thing so it doesn't look like a mess. :) Much appreciated.